# SQL: I am trying to add a foreign key but it give me error

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add a foreign key but I get an error:

> ORA-02298: cannot validate (user.SECTION_FK1) - parent keys not found

My code:

```
ALTER TABLE SECTION
ADD CONSTRAINT SECTION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY
(
  INSTRUCTOR_ID 
)
REFERENCES INSTRUCTOR
(
  INSTRUCTOR_ID 
)
ENABLE;
```

Comment: Are there existing data rows in both tables? Solution can be found here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02298_cannot_validate_parent_key.htm

Comment: SECTION table have a data but INSTRUCTOR table is empty.

Comment: Data is SECTION table but not in INSTRUCTOR is the problem. Obviously the INSTRUCTOR_ID in SECTION table can not find its reference in the INSTRUCTOR table. You can either delete the records from the SECTION table, or add all the INSTRUCTOR_ID from SECTION table to INSTRUCTOR table.

Comment: You (or someone, anyway) did things in the wrong order. First create table INSTRUCTOR, make the column INSTRUCTOR_ID the primary key, and insert all the data in the table. Then create table SECTION, make column INSTRUCTOR_ID the foreign key, and insert all the data. And make sure a SECTION does not have an INSTRUCTOR_ID that is not present in the INSTRUCTOR table (that would be a logical contradiction, having nothing to do with programming or with computers in general).

Comment: UPDATE SECTION SET INSTRUCTOR_ID=NULL; but it give me error too Error report -
ORA-01407: cannot update ("JKHALIQ"."SECTION"."INSTRUCTOR_ID") to NULL

Comment: how can I delete the data from the INSTRUCTOR_ID column in the section table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have ideally followed the whole process of creating tables as described in @mathguy's comment. Now you have ended up in a situation where the child table has data and parent does not.

So, one option with you (I assume you were not part of the whole table creation process.) is to populate the instructors with the data available in the `section`.

The `INSTRUCTOR_ID` in the table  `INSTRUCTOR` should be a `Primary key` or a `Unique key`, which too I assume it is. If not, take a look at this article how to create a `PRIMARY KEY` on the existing table  : https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php.

You may then populate the `INSTRUCTOR` table selecting the unique instructors from `SECTION`. An assumption in the first query here is that **none** of the other columns have `NOT NULL` or other check constraints.

```
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR (INSTRUCTOR_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT INSTRUCTOR_ID
FROM SECTION;

   Update INSTRUCTOR  SET <other columns> = <value>, .. where INSTRUCTOR_ID = <id>
....
...
```

*OR*

multiple inserts with distinct instructor_id exported from `SECTION`, modifying other values in a script.

```
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR (INSTRUCTOR_ID,other_columns, ....)
   VALUES ( <instructor_id>  ,  <other_column_values> ...,); 
INSERT INTO ..
```

So, once you have made sure that all the `instructor_id`s in the `section` table are available in the `INSTRUCTOR` , you may run your alter script to add foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE SECTION ADD CONSTRAINT SECTION_FK1 
FOREIGN KEY (INSTRUCTOR_ID) REFERENCES INSTRUCTOR (INSTRUCTOR_ID) ENABLE;
```